# sh404sef not working in localhost

Tags: url-rewriting, joomla2.5

I have installed the SH404SEF component for Joomla 2.5. It is working in my live site , but does not work in localhost.

I have enabled the mod_rewrite and added htaccess in my localhost. but it is not redirecting  and 404 error occurs. please Help
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create fresh installation of Joomla
- After that check whether there is.htacsess file,
- Else Create a .htaccess file and finally
- Install the Sh404sef Component  Using the Control Panel of Sh404sef
- Start the SEF process and you can able to see the result

**.htaccess Sample**

**At the End of .htaccess file , you will see**

```
## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing the variable shDefaultParams['sh404SEF_USE_NON_STANDARD_PORT'. Guess it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your Support @Yesceeohhh. I have missed .htaccess file and its worked